# Finding array objects from user input

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to make it so the user input for my code corresponds with the objects in my array, but I have no idea how to do this.

Basically, the assignment says to right a program that will grade final exams, each question has one of four possible answers ( a,b,c,d) and the first answer in the array should correspond to the first question in the exam. The program should them prompt the user for their answers to the exam, and should be compared with the first correct answer in the array and if it matches, it'll give them points.

Problem is, I can't for the life of me figure out how to compare user input to my array to see if it's the right thing they put in.

Here's what I have so far!

I know I'm awful at it, but I'm trying my best. Any help will be extremely appreciated.

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 int main (int argc, char * argv[])
 {
@autoreleasepool {
    NSArray *correctAnswers= [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"a", @"b ", @"c", @"d",nil];

    int sum = 0;
    int anwser;
    {

    NSLog(@"Please input test anwsers starting with 1:");
    scanf("%i",&anwser);
    }
    if ([correctAnswers containsObject:@(anwser)])  {
        sum = +10;
    }else {
        NSLog(@"Well that's not quite right...");
}

NSLog(@"The final score is:%d",sum);




}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@"a"` etc are NSString instances.

You would need to use NSString instance methods to compare them to the user input.  You can also do fast enumeration with collections like NSArray

```
for (NSString* ans in correctAnswers)
{
    if ([ans isEqualtoString:[NSString stringWithInt:anwser]]) sum+=10;
}
```

You could also use NSArray's `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` to search the array.

But you can't use  `containsObject` to compare strings... it just checks for a specific NSObject instance.

You also appear to be comparing an int to a char... but that's outside the scope of your question.

Comment: Thank you, still having problems but I think you are pushing me in the right direction

Comment: In general, the world of converting between C-types and Obj-C-types is actually quirky and verbose, with the exception that you can now box things with @.  Like @2 rather than [NSNumber numberWithInt:2]. It's easiest to stick with just NSObject subclasses when you can, but to remember that any C operator like == or + or - or < is not going to be overloaded to work with NSString or NSNumber.  And any NSNumber or NSString is just a pointer to an object that is an NSObject subclass.